# jQuery | Assistance needed with listview and passing data when clicked to a new page

Tags: jquery, ajax, listview, mobile

I have a list of items that is dynamically pulled from a web service.
It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfXih.png

What I want to happen, is I want the list item that is clicked, to somehow be declared as a variable....and the information for the clicked item, to be passed onto another page. I have no idea how to go about doing this, and was hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

So far I have been able to come up with this, but the variable 'someData' keeps coming back undefined.

```
$('#dogs ul').click(function(e) {
var someData = jQuery(this).data('<li>');
alert(someData);
});

}
```

Here is the code that brings all the information together into the listview:

```
$(data).find('NewDataSet').each(function(i) {
    var listView = $('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-theme="b">').data('role', 'listview');

    $(data).find('Table').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).find('ShortDesc').text();
        var description = $(this).find('LongDesc').text();
        var thumbnail = $(this).find('ThumbURL').text();
        var listItem = $('<li/>');
        $('<a href="#"><img id="bla" src="' + thumbnail + '"><div id="desc"><h4>' + title + '</h4> <p> <br/>' + description + '</p></div>').appendTo(listItem);
        $(listItem).appendTo(listView);
    });

    $(listView).appendTo('#dogs');
});


$('#dogs ul').listview();
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, or show me what I'm doing wrong it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're pretty close. You can store the data on each `li` element as they are created using jQuery.data().

```
$(data).find('Table').each(function() {

    //...

    var tableData = $(this); // 'this', in your example, refers to the Table data
    var listItem = $('<li/>').data('TableData', tableData);
});
```

To get it back out and pass it along to another page, you can handle the click and post the data to another page. You can also append the data in the querystring if that's easier.

```
$('#dogs ul li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var tableData = $(this).data('TableData');
    $.mobile.changePage("anotherpage.php", {
        type: "post",
        data: $(tableData).serialize() // I'm not sure of your data format, so serialize() this may not work
    });
});
```

Comment: Derek, we're almost there I think. 

I'm using HTML5 in a mobile app, so my pages are all divs with page id's. 

Using the code you provided, I get 'error loading page' and redirected back to my 'home' page. 

My data isn't anything fancy like json, or jsonp. 

Any idea whats wrong in this picture? 

Here is the latest code:

http://pastebin.com/ZYtwUndg   

    I should also note that I am still a beginner in jQuery, so I don't quite understand EVERYTHING and how it works. If you could exlplain what the above is doing a little more for me, I'd be able to better understand it.

THANKS!

Comment: Also; I should note that when the alert I have in there comes into play, it's coming back undefined!

    e.stopPropagation();
    var tableData = $(this).data('TableData');
    alert(tableData);
    $.mobile.changePage("SelectedDog", {
    type: "post",
    data: $(tableData).serialize()

Comment: Your click event handler is defined on the entire '#dogs ul', not the individual list items. Try using `$('#dogs ul li').click(...)` and report back.

Comment: Okay, now i'm receiving [object Object] in the alert here. Thoughts?

Comment: That's a good sign. Try alerting `$(tableData).find('ShortDesc').text()`. You should get the short description. Typically, there'd be some sort of unique ID for the dog, yes? Once you have the values you need, you can assemble a URL or post data and transition to another page.

Comment: Awesome! That works, now I just have to work on the transition. I am going to do some research on this, if you have any additional information that might be helpful please, let me hear it! You've been an awesome asset thus far. I thank you for that

Comment: Hey Derek, I've decided to make some changes to my design. Instead of going to another page, I simply created a new div in which I want to take the 'tableData' that you showed me how to create, and fill the new DIV with. 

Currently, I am trying like this:

$('LongDesc').appendTo('#selected');
$('tableData').appendTo('#selected'); 
$(tableData).appendTo('#selected');

...and I've tried a few other variations but no luck, can you point me in the right direction?

(PS) Sorry for the formatting, indenting four spaces doesn't work and neither does the `tick` method. /:

Comment: Nevermind! I've got it, I had to create new variables for the selected dogs info and was able to pass it on successfully. 

Thanks for all the help!